# Cataloging file names over 256 characters

Tags: powershell

I am brand new to scripting (or coding of any sort). I had an issue where I wanted to generate csv files to catalog directories and certain file names to aid in my work. I was able to put something together that works for what I need. With one exception, long names return the following error:

> ERROR: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Here is my script:

```
Write-Host "Andy's File Lister v2.2"
$drive = Read-Host "R or Q?"
$client = Read-Host "What is the client's name as it appears on the R or Q drive?"
$path= "${drive}:\${client}"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -dir | Select-Object FullName | Export-CSV $home\downloads\"$client directories.csv"
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include *.pdf, *.jp*, *.xl*, *.doc* | Select-Object FullName | Export-CSV $home\downloads\"$client files.csv"
Write-Host "Check your downloads folder."
Pause
```

As I said, I am brand new to this. Is there a different command I could use, or a way to tell the script to skip directory names or files over a certain length?

Thanks!

Comment: FYIZ : the limit is an old limitation. In Windows 10 you can enable long file path support through a policy setting, that will solve the problem. If you are using an older version you can use PInvoke to get support for long file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of the .Length child property of the .FullName property of each item you check, and if it's greater than 256 characters, use Out-Null:

Ex.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users\myusername\desktop\myfolder

foreach($item in $items)
{
     if($item.FullName.Length -lt 256)
     {
          do some stuff
     }
     elseif($item.FullName.Length)
     {
          Out-Null
     }
}
```

If you want to check the parent folder's path as well, you could check

```
$item.Parent.FullName.Length
```

in your processing as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should close your strings on lines 5 and 6.

Instead of using `"`, you should use `\"` because currently your script parses the entire line 6 as a one string.